# Prove that $Tv = \alpha v$ for some $\alpha \in \Bbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

**Assume $T:\Bbb R^2 \rightarrow \Bbb R ^2$ is a linear transformation with $trT=0, detT<0$.
Prove that $Tv = \alpha v$ for some $\alpha \in \Bbb R$.**

So far I proved that T is diagonizable: if $detT=-k$ for some $0<k\in\Bbb R$, then the characteristic polynomial of T would be $P_T(t)=t^2-trT\cdot t+detT=(t-\sqrt{k})(t+\sqrt{k})$. So, exist two linearly independent eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$ such that $Tv_1=\sqrt{k}v_1, Tv_2=-\sqrt{k}v_2$. How does this lead me to conclude that it's a scalar transformation, if $k>0$ as we first assumed? What am I missing?

Comment: The claim is false: The map $T v = \alpha v$ has determinant $\alpha^2 \geq 0$ (and the hypothesis is satisfiable, as it holds, e.g., for reflections).

Comment: @Travis Aha!!! I knew there was a mistake in the question!! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. (The claim is so wrong that it's hard to guess what the intended question was in the first place...)

Comment: Not clear why that matters, since $Tv=\alpha v$ doesn't satify $\mathrm{tr }T=0$. @Travis

Comment: So it is not false.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You seem to have parsed the question as, "Show that $Tv = \alpha v$ for some $\alpha \in \Bbb R$ *and some nonzero $v \in \Bbb R^2$*, equivalently, that $T$ has a real eigenvalue, whereas I read "Prove that $T v = \alpha v$...* to be an assertion that $T$ is a scalar transformation, i.e., that the equation holds for *all* $v$.

Comment: Given that the claim is false otherwise you are probably right that that's the intended meaning, but in that case the wording of the problem looks pretty misleading to me.

Comment: Ah, I see, yes, you are correct, the statement is false as written. @Travis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this circumstance, the characteristic polynomial of $T$ is $p(\lambda)=\lambda^2+\det T$. So, in particular, $T^2=(-\det T)I$.

You can work that out explicitly - if $T=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&-a\end{pmatrix}$ then:

$$T^2=\begin{pmatrix}a^2+bc&ab-ba\\ca-ac&bc+(-a)^2\end{pmatrix}=(a^2+bc)I$$

and $\det T=-(a^2+bc)$.

Letting $\alpha = \sqrt{-\det T}$. Then for any $v$, let $Pv=(T-\alpha I)v$ and $Qv=(T+\alpha I)v$.

Then show that $QP=0$.

Now, pick any $v\neq 0$.

If $Pv=0$ then $Tv=\alpha v$ and you are done.

If $Pv\neq 0$ then let $v'=Pv\neq 0$. Then $Qv'=QPv=0$ so $Tv'=(-\alpha)v'$, and you are again done.